# How do I create a basic looping calculation in sql to avoid doing 200+ Joins

Tags: postgresql, loops

All -

I have a basic issue, which is becoming a major nightmare.

I am creating a payment schedule table for future dates.  In order to calculate the future balances, I need to continuously reduce the starting balance in Table A on each date, based upon the future payment amount in table B.

The problem is that I have to left join Table B based upon what the balance is in Table A, and do that for every single row because the ending balance in Row 1 is the starting balance in Row 2, and the ending balance in Row 2, is the starting balance in Row 3.  This is a cumulative / looping calculation.

Here is a depiction of what I am trying to do:

[![Table Examples][1]][1]

Here is the actual SQL:

```
     with dates_rns as (
  select 
  
  a.loan_id
,as_of_date as payment_date
,upb_usd as starting_balance
,principal_amount as payment
,new_upb as new_balance   
,row_number() over (partition by loan_id  order by a.as_of_date) as rn
    from scratchpad.iit1 a 
  where row_value < 100
), payment_sched as (
  select loan_id, payment_date, starting_balance, 
         payment, new_balance,  rn
    from dates_rns a
   where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.loan_id, n.payment_date, 
         p.new_balance as starting_balance,
         least(b.principal_amount, p.new_balance), 
         greatest(p.new_balance - b.principal_amount, 0.00) as new_balance, 
         n.rn
    from dates_rns n         -- 'n' is for this payment
    join payment_sched p     -- 'p' is for previous payment
      on n.rn = p.rn + 1 
    join scratchpad.collectability_1_Princ b           -- payment lookup
      on b.loan_id = p.loan_id
     and round(b.previous_upb) > round(p.new_balance)
     and round(b.remaining_upb) <= round(p.new_balance)
)
select * 
  from payment_sched
```

Comment: Please show samples of the data in Table A and Table B.  The screenshot is not sufficient because it looks like you are showing what you are trying to do rather than what you have to work with.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, good call.  I've attached sample data from A and B.  Table B is being joined to Table A so that the new balance in Table A essentially determined what the payment amount in table B should be.  New Balance in table A must be < previous balance in Table B and >= remaining balance in Table B

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a recursion query here.  These queries can go haywire depending on your data, so I will restrict it to one `loan_id`, passed in the `params` CTE.

Change the `12345` to a valid `loan_id`, and see if this works for you.  Please let me know in comments if it gives you trouble.

You cannot use an `outer join` inside of the recursive CTE, so `table_b` has to cover the full range.

```
with recursive params as (
  select 12345 as loan_id
), dates_rns as (
  select a.loan_id, a.payment_date, a.starting_balance, a.payment, a.new_balance,
         row_number() over (order by a.payment_date) as rn
    from params p
    join table_a a on a.loan_id = p.loan_id
), payment_sched as (
  select loan_id, payment_date, starting_balance, 
         payment, new_balance,  rn
    from dates_rns a
   where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.loan_id, n.payment_date, 
         p.new_balance as starting_balance,
         least(b.payment, p.new_balance), 
         greatest(p.new_balance - b.payment, 0.00) as new_balance, 
         n.rn
    from dates_rns n         -- 'n' is for this payment
    join payment_sched p     -- 'p' is for previous payment
      on n.rn = p.rn + 1 
    join table_b b           -- payment lookup
      on b.loan_id = p.loan_id
     and round(b.previous_balance) > round(p.new_balance)
     and round(b.remaining_balance) <= round(p.new_balance)
)
select * 
  from payment_sched;
```

Comment: Just wondering if you had any thoughts on boosting hte performance?  This solution actually works well and seems to produce the same result as the 100 Left join method I was using before.   Any thoughts on boosting performance?  The only downside is I need to run this for 20K + unique id's and the performance is very very slow.   I also realized snowflake as an iteration limit of 100 which stinks, so I will need to find a workaround for that as well.  You are the man though!!  If I can figure out performance and a workaround for the iterations , I'm golden

Comment: @sqlbrah Sorry, but I think this particular task is a poor fit for a DWH and for SQL in general.  Hitting the recursion limit is a bad sign.   You may want to put in a support ticket with Snowflake to see if cluster keying and/or performing these calculations in a stored procedure where looping is available can help.